# Is there a way prevent libcurl from buffering?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am using libcurl with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to download a certain file.

I ask for a certain buffer size using CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE.

When my callback function is called the first time and I get about that many bytes, there are much more data actually downloaded.

For example, if I ask for 1024 bytes of data, when I first get that, the process has already consumed 100K of data (based on process explorer and similar tools. I can see the continuous stream of data and ACKs in wireshark), so I assume it is downloading in advance and buffering the data.

The thing I am trying to achieve here is to be able to cancel the retrieval based on first few chunks of data without downloading anything that is unnecessary.

Is there a way to prevent that sort of buffering and only download the next chunk of data once I have finished processing the current one (or at least not to buffer tens and hundreds of kilobytes)?

I would prefer the solution to be server agnostic, so CURLOPT_RANGE won't actually work here.

Comment: There are several layers of buffering involved - the kernel buffer, the socket buffer, and libcurl's buffer. You are not really going to be able to do what you want. The kernel buffers what it wants, and libcurl won't go below 1024 for its buffer. You *can* use `CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET` to access the socket, and then use `setsockopt()` to set its buffer size, but that is more advisory when using small buffers. So you are best off just letting the system buffer what it needs, cancel at your earliest opportunity, and on the next transfer just ignore whatever you received on the previous transfer.

Comment: `CURLOPT_RANGE` is the solution I was recommending in my answer, then I noticed that you said you don't want to use it. Unfortunately, I think it's the only thing you can do.

Comment: TCP just doesn't work the way you think. It doesn't involved the recipient requesting data, the sender just sends continuously.

Comment: @Barmar what you described applies to HTTP, but the OP didn't specify which protocol is being used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau FTP is similar. What protocols work differently?

Comment: Whether you set a small buffer or a large buffer your callback will just keep getting called until all the data arrived or you aborted the operation in your callback.

Comment: @RemyLebeau quick test shows that what you suggested may very well be a solution. I will need to test some more how reliable this is, but in my test program the only source of buffering seems to have been OS buffer controlled by SO_RCVBUF. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar True, but unless the portion of data was actually received, the next packet won't be sent and won't be counted as network traffic. It's fine by me if the server tries to push more data, while the buffer is full and then I just drop the connection.